# How do I select a second column for the rows who have duplicates on the first column?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a table with two columns:

- City
- Country

I want a result set that includes all of the City values. For the rows that the same City value I want to also include the country column. An example of my desired result set is as follows:

```
City
----------------
Chicago
New York
Toronto
London, Canada
London, England
Los Angeles
```

#### Note

The point of interest is the duplicate city names of "London" include a comma, space, and the country name to differentiate them.

How do I achieve this with a MySQL statement? I have tried a couple of things using `group by` and `having` clauses but I couldn't get my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT a.city AS city
    FROM YOUR_TABLE a
GROUP BY a.city
  HAVING COUNT(a.country) = 1
UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT(b.city, ', ', b.country) AS city
   FROM YOUR_TABLE b
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM YOUR_TABLE c
                 WHERE c.city = b.city
              GROUP BY c.city
                HAVING COUNT(c.country) > 1)
ORDER BY city
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. There is one small issue that I'm hoping you can help with. For city names that have unicode characters it is returning `NULL`. Any ideas?

Comment: @nick: That's a collation issue, and depending on the collation you might not reliably get the desired result.  It's a separate question, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following SQL statements assuming name of table in cityTable

```
    SELECT cityTable.City  , cityTable.Country  FROM cityTable INNER JOIN ( SELECT City FROM cityTable GROUP BY City HAVING COUNT(City) > 1 ) as tempTable ON cityTable.City = tempTable.City

    SELECT City FROM Table GROUP BY City HAVING  COUNT(City) = 1
```

First Query will give all duplicates city with country name and second query will give all cities which are not repeated with only city name.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005863/how-do-i-select-a-second-column-for-the-rows-who-have-duplicates-on-the-first-col/6005886#6005886) is perfectly workable.  This is another way to approach the problem:

```
   SELECT CASE
          WHEN repeated IS NULL THEN city
          ELSE                       city || ', ' || country
          END AS city
LEFT JOIN (SELECT city AS repeated
             FROM cities
         GROUP BY 1
           HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) d
          ON cities.city = d.repeated
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t work in MySQL, which does not yet support windowing (AFAIK!), but for the record, in a RDBMS that *does*, you can do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (count(*) > 1) THEN (city || ', ' || country) ELSE city END
OVER (PARTITION BY city)
FROM city_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE city IN (
SELECT city, 
 COUNT(city) AS NumOccurrences
FROM table
GROUP BY city
HAVING ( COUNT(city) > 1 )
```

Comment: I didn't say anything about deleting rows